# Why does the import keyword work in react and not in a normal npm init project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

What does the react library do to make importing an npm package in the front end work?  You cannot do this in a plain vanilla javascript setup with npm init, it throws and error.

Comment: To clarify, importing an npm package such as moment, or axios, cannot be imported as it is in React like import axios from '../pathfile';  this works in react but not a standard npm init package.

Comment: You have to setup a transpilator (babel, or something equivalent) to convert ES6 import/export into `require()`, because nodejs does not support it, out of the box

Answer (score 1):

import and export are ES6 syntax which are not fully supported in plain Javascript. React projects generally use Babel or other transpilers to convert the latest ES6 and later syntaxes to the older and browser supported Javascript code. So, you are allowed to use import and export in React while you can't do it if you create a simple javascript project bootstrapping it through npm. However, you can [configure babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) in your simple project as well.

Comment: `not fully supported in plain Javascript` that statement is wrong, it is not well supported by the engines at the moment. EcmaScript is the standard describing the JavaScript language. So JavaScript is the commonly used name for the EcmaScript specification (that the names differ has historical reasons).

Comment: Ok so I used babel and it transpiles the import keyword to require.  Require is not understood by the browser.  Would this just be some further configuration I need to make in babel as I have the presets set to "env" which I understand covers everything.